# How to get id of post inside of plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to retrive post id inside  plugin.
I tried

```
global $post;
 $a_Id=$post->ID;
```

and

```
global $wp_query;
$thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID;
```

and

```
var_dump(get_the_ID()); //shows just null
```

How i can retrieve it?

The idea is to get language of post from Custom Fields
and feed it into Global Translator plugin as a BASE LANG

EDIT:
I can retrive id from $_GET['p'] on development server but on production i
have pretty urls so i dont have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you know what the ID is for an particular post you could use

```
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
```

to show a listing of anything that you can get your hands on.
Look through the output for the ID that you know and then use the path that it shows to get there.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that this constant is not available at the place i need it.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing with the post ID? When exactly do you need it? I'm guessing you are using this very early in your plugin file, when the query is not yet parsed. The query is parsed after the hook `parse_query` is fired.

Comment: I try to get post id to retrive Custom Filed of it to get what language it is written and i need it at the beginning to set is as constant . parse_query is added in add_action. Should i use do_action() somehow?